# delete image ins database mysql from dashboard php

Tags: php

hi i need help i have problem in my code and i can't figure the solutions please help me .
this is the dashboard:
[image dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCyRw.png)

and this is problem after click on delete:
[delete problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NqFr.png)

and this is my code php of posts file:

```
    <?php

/*
===========================================================
=== Manage Members Page                                 ===
=== You can add | edit | delete Members from here       ===
===========================================================
*/
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {

        include 'init.php';
        $pageTitle = 'Posts';
        $do = isset($_GET['do']) ? $_GET['do'] :  'Manage' ;

        //Start Manage Page
        if ($do == 'Manage'){ // Manage Members Page 

        $sort = 'ASC';

        $sort_arry = array('ASC', 'DESC');

        if(isset($_GET['sort']) && in_array($_GET['sort'], $sort_arry)) {

            $sort = $_GET['sort'];

        }

        $stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY Ordering $sort");

        $stmt2->execute();

        $rows = $stmt2->fetchAll(); 


        ?>

        <h1 class="text-center"> Manage Posts </h1>
        <div class="container categories">
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Manage Posts 
                <div class="ordering pull-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-sort"> </i>Ordering: [
                    <a class="<?php if ($sort == 'ASC') { echo 'active'; } ?>" href="?sort=ASC">Asc </a> |
                    <a class="<?php if ($sort == 'DESC') { echo 'active'; } ?>" href="?sort=DESC">Desc </a>
                    ]
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                <?php 
                  foreach ($rows as $image) {
                    echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 "><div class="thumbnail">';
                    echo '<h2 class="h4">'.$image['Name']. '</h2><div class="main">';
                    echo '<img src="data:image;base64,'.$image['Image'].' " alt="image name" title="image title" width="255" heigth="255">';
                    echo   '</div>';
                    echo      '<table class="table table-bordered">';
                    echo          '<tr>';
                    echo            '<td>' . "<a href='posts.php?do=Edit&id=". $image['ID'] ."' class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> edit</a>" . '</td>';

                    echo            '<td>' . "<a href='posts.php?do=Delete&id=". $image['ID'] ."' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-close'></i> Delete</a>" . '</td>';
                    echo        '</tr>';
                    echo      '</table>';
                echo    '</div>';
                echo  '</div>';
                  }
                ?>

            </div>


<?php       } elseif ($do == 'Add') { //add Member page ?>

            <h1 class="text-center"> ajouter un nouveau post </h1>
                <div class="container">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?do=Insert" method="POST">
                    <!-- start Username fieled -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Titre</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" name="image-name"  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="username pour se connecter dans le site Web"  required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end Username fieled -->
                        <!-- start Password fieled -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" placeholder="mot de passe doit être difficile et complexe"  required/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end Password fieled -->
                        <!-- start Full name fieled -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-sm-2" for="categorie">Categories:</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                                <select class="form-control" name="categorie">
                                <?php
                                $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `categories`");

                                // Execute the Statments

                                $stmt->execute();           

                                // Assign to variable 

                                $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
                                ?>
                                <?php
                                    foreach ($rows as $cat) {
                                        echo "<option value='" . $cat['ID'] . "'>". $cat['Name'] . "</option>";
                                    }
                                ?>
                              </select>
                              </div>

                            </div>
                        <!-- end Full name fieled -->
                        <!-- start submit fieled -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end submit fieled -->
                    </form>
                </div>



    <?php   
            } elseif ($do == 'Insert') {

                //insert Members Page
                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

                    echo "<h1 class='text-center'> insert an post </h1>";
                    echo "<div class='container'>";

                    // Get variable from the form
                    $name   = $_POST['image-name'];
                    $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                    $image= file_get_contents($image);
                    $image= base64_encode($image);
                    $cat    = $_POST['categorie'];

                    //validate the form
                    $formErrors = array();

                    if (strlen($name) < 4) {

                        $formErrors[] = "title name cant be less then <strong> 4 caracter</strong>";
                    }

                    if (strlen($name) > 20) {

                        $formErrors[] = "title name cant be More then <strong> 20 caracter</strong>";
                    }


                    if (empty($name)) {

                        $formErrors[] = "Username Cant Be  <strong>Empty</strong>";

                    }


                    // loop into eroos array and echo it
                    foreach ($formErrors as $Error) {

                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>" . $Error . "</div>";
                    }

                    // check if There is no error procced the operations
                    if (empty($formErrors)) {

                        // check if user exist in database

                        $check = checkItem("Username", "users", $user);

                        if ($check == 1) {

                            $theMsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Sorry this user is exist </div>";

                            redirectHome($theMsg, 'back');

                        } else {

                            // Insert User info into database
                            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO posts(Name, Image, Cat_id)
                                                    VALUES (:name, :image, :cat)");
                            $stmt->execute(array(
                                'name' => $name,
                                'image' => $image,
                                'cat' => $cat,
                                ));

                            // echo success message
                            $theMsg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" . $stmt->rowCount() . ' Record Inserted </div> ';

                            redirectHome($theMsg, 'back', 5);
                        }

                    }


                } else {

                    echo "<div class='container'>";

                    $theMsg = '<div class="alert alert-danger"> Sorry you cant browse this page directely </div>';

                    redirectHome($theMsg, 'back', 5); // 6 is secend of redirect to page in function

                    echo "</div>";
                }

                echo "</div>";

            } elseif ($do == 'Edit') {  // Edit Page

            //check if GET request userid Is numeric & Get The integer value of it

            $post = isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;  

            //sellect All Data Depend On This ID
            $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ID = ? LIMIT 1");

            // execute Query

            $stmt->execute(array($post));

            //fetch the Data

            $row = $stmt->fetch();

            // The row count

            $count = $stmt->rowCount();

            // If Ther's Such Id show The Form

            if ($count > 0) { ?>

                <h1 class="text-center"> Modifier Post </h1>
                <div class="container">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?do=Update" method="POST">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 panel"> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
                    <!-- start title fieled -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Titre</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required  value="<?php echo $row['Name']; ?>" >

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end title field -->
                        <!-- start image filed -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">image</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                                <input type="file" name="image"  class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end image filed -->

                        <!-- start Categories filed -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-sm-2" for="categorie">Categories:</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                                <select class="form-control" name="categorie">
                                <?php
                                $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `categories`");

                                // Execute the Statments

                                $stmt->execute();           

                                // Assign to variable 

                                $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
                                ?>
                                <?php
                                    foreach ($rows as $cat) {
                                        echo "<option value='" . $cat['ID'] . "'>". $cat['Name'] . "</option>";
                                    }
                                ?>
                              </select>
                              </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- Categories end-->

                        <!-- start submit fieled -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="sauvegarder" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end submit fieled -->
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
        <?php 

            // if there's No Such id Show Error Message

            } else {

                echo "<div class='container'>";

                $theMsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Theres is no such Id</div>";

                redirectHome($theMsg);

                echo "</div>";

            }

        } elseif ($do == 'Update') {

            echo "<h1 class='text-center'> mis a jour Membre </h1>";
            echo "<div class='container'>";

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

                // Get variable from the form
                $id = $_POST['id'];
                $name   = $_POST['name'];
                $image  = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                $image  = file_get_contents($image);
                $image  = base64_encode($image);
                $cat    = $_POST['categorie'];


                //validate the form

                $formErrors = array();

                if (empty($name)) {

                    $formErrors[] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Username Cant Be  <strong>Empty</strong> </div>";

                }

                if (empty($image)) {

                    $formErrors[] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>FullName Cant Be <strong>Empty</strong></div>";

                }

                if (empty($cat)) {

                    $formErrors[] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Email Cant Be <strong>Empty</strong></div>";

                }

                // loop into eroos array and echo it

                foreach ($formErrors as $Error) {
                    echo $Error;
                }

                // check if There is no error procced the operations

                if (empty($formErrors)) {

                    // Update The Database With This Info

                    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE posts SET Name = ? , Image = ? , Cat_id = ? WHERE ID = ?");
                    $stmt->execute(array($name, $image, $cat, $id));

                    // echo success message

                    $theMsg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" . $stmt->rowCount() . ' Record Updated </div> ';

                    redirectHome($theMsg, 'back');

                }


            } else {

                $theMsg = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry you cant browse this page directely </div>';

                redirectHome($theMsg);

            }

            echo "</div>";
        }

        elseif ($do == 'Delete') { // Delete Member Page


            echo "<h1 class='text-center'> Delete Membre </h1>";
            echo "<div class='container'>";

                //check if GET request userid Is numeric & Get The integer value of it

                $id = isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;  

                //sellect All Data Depend On This ID

                $check = checkItem('id', 'posts', $id);

                // If Ther's Such Id show The Form

                if ($check > 0) {

                    $stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE ID = :id");

                    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);

                    $stmt->execute();

                    $theMsg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" . $stmt->rowCount() . ' Record Deleted </div> ';

                    redirectHome($theMsg);

                } else {

                    $theMsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>This id not exist</div>";

                    redirectHome($theMsg);
                }

            echo "</div>";
        }

        include $tpl . 'footer.php';
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php')       ;
        exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

from the error, id is the problem.

```
isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])
```

i think what u want is

```
(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) )//close parantheses in wrong position
```

Comment: not working :(  please read all the code to get understand thanks

Comment: @Oussama changed my code, sorry , should be before all conditions  and after isset also